# Bson unable to find codec

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, quarkus

I am using Quarkus to build a web service which takes in an input, processes it and stores some results as objects into MongoDB. However, it is throwing me an error about "Bson unable to find a codec". I believe it should be related to how my object is constructed.

Sample attributes of my object:

```
public class ResultsResponse{
    //Job id for tracking if using db to store
    private String jobId;
    private Boolean matched;
    private long timeElapsedInMillis;
    private String source1;
    private String source2;
    private Double absoluteTolerance;
    private Integer maxResultsLimit;
    private List<List<String>> missingRows;
    private List<String> headers;
    private List<List<String>> acceptableRows;
```

From the googling that I have done, I believe it is because Bson is unable to map a `List<List<String>` into a mongodb data type. I also followed the quarkus documentation [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#configuring-the-mongodb-database) to create a custom codec provider but I don't quite understand how exactly I can do it.

Appreciate if anyone is able to provide any inputs and feel free to ask for more information if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same problem when using PanacheMongo. The solution for me was to make the fields public. Panache requires public fields.

And by defining getters/setters you ensure encapsulation:

"And thanks to our field access rewrite, when your users read person.name they will actually call your getName() accessor, and similarly for field writes and the setter. This allows for proper encapsulation at runtime as all fields calls will be replaced by the corresponding getter/setter calls."

See https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache for more information

If you are not using MongoPanache you can ignore me. or perhaps it also fixes it for normal mongo.